# Ленивый v-model vue select?

Tags: vue.js, select

пользуюсь плагином vue-select , с которого идёт запрос через v-model на сервер
Каждый раз когда я ввожу буку в инпут у меня постоянно идёт запрос на сервер - что не есть хорошо

Я хочу поставить v-model.lazy - но он у меня не работает, Моя задача делать запрос на сервер через пару секунд когда юзер ввёл данные в инпут

Answer (score 0):

Используйте паттерн debounce, под vue есть готовые реализации https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-debounce например

Comment: Есть более адекватный вариант чтобы не устанавливать библу?

Comment: самому написать, там строчек на 15-20 https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Что??? Как сделать v-model.lazy ? )

Comment: v-model.lazy и инпут будет обновлять модель только на событие change, только как это связано с задержкой запросов?